# Show that $ (\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 $ with induction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

> Let $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R},\quad i=1,\dots,n$. Show that
>   $$(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$$
>   where the equality holds if and only if $x_i=\lambda y_i$ where
>   $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$

If I think I already saw it in some place but I don't remember how to proof

For $n=1$
$$(x_1y_1)^2=x_1^2y_1^2\leq x_1^2\times y_1^2$$

Assuming that is true for $n=k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$(\sum_{i=1}^k x_iy_i)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2$$
Then we need to show that for $n=k+1$ it is true too
$$(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x_iy_i)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x_i^2\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} y_i^2$$

I'm stuck now, I thought it was something related to moving the series but I got nowhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: @Roland Please, have a look at this (12 proofs): http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matsefi/Octogon/volumes/volume1/article1_19.pdf